# Find first value and returning the second value in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list that looks like:

```
list = [
("Element A", 01),
("Element B", 02),
("Element C", 03),
("Element D", 04)
]
```

Knowing the first value I need a way of getting the second value.

Comment: Use a dictionary? `dict(my_list)['Element A']`

Comment: Alright, what's the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, naming a variable `list` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to search it once, just scan the list:

```
lst = [
("Element A", 1),
("Element B", 2),
("Element C", 3),
("Element D", 4)
]
key = "Element B"
val = [elt[1] for elt in lst if elt[0] == key][0]
print(val)
```

gives as expected `2`

If you want to do many searches, convert the list to a dict:

```
d = dict(lst)
val = d[key]
```

also gives `2`

Comment: Converting to a dict looks cleaner and worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your using a list while you really need a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

This way you can define your information like so:

```
mydict = {
"Element A": 01,
"Element B": 02,
"Element C": 03,
"Element D": 04
}
```

and retrieving the value is as easy as:

```
mydict['Element A']
```

[EDIT] Serge's answer is more concise.